# Code Not calculating correctly Cast /NullIF

Tags: sql, express

I’m trying to calculate CNC machine efficiency.  My code doesn’t calculate correctly.  I’m not sure why.  For instance, The Completed value is 2.  The PPHOURGOAL is 1.  The 8 is for an 8-hour shift.

```
cast(((Completed / 8) /NULLIF(Completed,0) / (PPHOURGOAL  * 8) )* 100 as dec(5,4))  as EightHourShiftEfficiency,   ---Divide the previously calculated production rate by the maximum rate and multiply by 100 to calculate the efficiency rate.
```

Calculation should be as `((2/8)/(1*8))*100 = 2`.  Which should translate to `((.25)/(8))*100=2`

But the system is returning `1.5625` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that integer division is the culprit.  Does this do what you want?

```
cast(((Completed / 8.0) /NULLIF(Completed, 0.0) / (PPHOURGOAL * 8.0) ) * 100.0 as dec(5, 4)) as E
```

Comment: That didn't do it.  I get the same results.

Comment: So I broke the code down to this.  Completed /8 = 2/8 = 0.25.  as soon as I add the /NULLIF(Completed, 0) my results change to 0.125000000000000000

Is there another way to exclude zero’s from my calculation?  The Completed column almost always has a zero somewhere.  If I don’t exclude them, I’ll end up with the divide by zero error.

Comment: why will you include NULL in a math operation?

Comment: Found the error of my ways.  My select statement was doubling rows that caused my calculations to be off.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the error of my ways.  My select statement was doubling rows that caused my calculations to be off.